# DB2 Connect - Unicode Support from VB Application

Tags: unicode, db2

I am trying to insert '€' char in Db2 Database.  My Db2 database is in zOS.   (v.8.0) and my Db2 client version is 9.1 FP5.  I am trying this using ODBC Connection via ADODB in Visual Basic or C# code.

But junk char is getting inserted.   '€' symbol is not inserting.

Is there any option to set the CodePage 1252 at connection level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used DISABLEUNICODE = '1' to SELECT / INSERT '€' symbols from VB